# How to speed up server while using pusher events laravel and redis

Tags: laravel-5, digital-ocean, pusher

Here I have digital ocean server + Laravel 5.8 Project set up with + Mysql + Redis + Pusher Echo Events.

Backend : Laravel

Frontend : React

> Server Configuration : 16 GB Memory / 50 GB Disk / LON1 - Ubuntu
> 18.04.3 (LTS) x64 @doydoy

The server is facing big traffic everyday.

So Found the issue like pusher's socket is taking much memory and cpu usage which causes server low in performance and which impacts on website traffic as well.

So how can I speed or improve it ?

I have used frontend event.listeners() to auto refresh the changes.
So sometimes it might call another API to get updated state.

Here is the graph for it.

Pusher Graph
[image]
CPU graph
[image]

Comment: How have you identified the cause of the memory and CPU usage? 
Is it using these resources constantly or when an event is received?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Server Configuration : 16 GB Memory / 50 GB Disk / LON1 - Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64 @doydoy.
I am quite sure it is happening because of event. Which is using socket internally and for that every new updated details event have been called and creating new instance object and occupied memory and than turning into high memory and CPU usage to cause low performance of the server. But can't distinguish the solution of this problem.